# Was Mordo a self-fulfilling prophecy or were there other consequences?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange-2016

In the MCU film "Doctor Strange", sorcerer/enforcer Mordo splits from the group after Doctor Strange

> uses the Eye of Agamotto to 'rewind' time and restore the Hong Kong sanctum.

While discussing what just happened, Mordo reiterates his belief that the end does not justify the means, believing that the act can only bring even worse consequences:

> **Wong:** We did it.
>
> **Mordo:** Yes. [scoffs] Yes, we did it. [pauses] By *also* violating the natural law.
>
> **Strange:** Look around you. It's over.
>
> **Mordo:** You *still* think there will be no consequences, Strange? [pauses] No price to pay? [shakes head] We broke the rules... just
>   like her. The bill... comes... due. Always! A reckoning.
>
> [Mordo begins to turn away]
>
> **Mordo:** I will follow this path no longer.

We later find that Mordo is now

> hunting down magic-users, apparently now believing that none are responsible enough to possess the power of magic.

Since everything else seems to have turned out okay, it seems to me that Mordo himself is the only negative consequence of Strange's actions.

**Has anyone involved with the film mentioned that this event will have other consequences down the road, or has Mordo become a self-fulfilling prophecy?**

Comment: Or the possible consequence of Strange bringing the Time Stone out into the open like that brings it to the attention of Thanos.

Comment: @phantom42 - true, we may have to wait for future movies to find out. I was just wondering if anyone had said something about it already.

Comment: I don't really think Mordo is a consequence on the level of an implied threat to unravel the universe like time travel usually comes with.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, there are other consequences.

Mordo will

> return in *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022). He is in the trailer released as an after-credits scene of *Spider-Man: No Way Home*.

**The full extent of his involvement is as-yet-unknown** (the film releases in the U.S. on May 4, 2022). However,

> Mordo is portrayed as a villain in the trailer.

It is unknown whether or not he Blipped (was snapped away by Thanos for 5 years). However, regardless of that fact, his goal is to fix what he thinks is wrong with the world:

> MORDO: Power has a purpose.
>
> PANGBORN: Why are you doing this?
>
> MORDO: **Because I see at long last what's wrong with the world. Too many sorcerers.**
>
> <sup>*Doctor Strange* (2016); emphasis added</sup>

Mordo is attempting to destroy the sorcerers of Earth and to take people's magic, because they do not use it to honor natural law.

Comment: I may not have been clear in the original question. Mordo becoming a bad guy appears to be the only negative consequence of Strange's actions. Anything ELSE that Mordo does beyond that point is on Mordo, not Strange. Perhaps I should have asked... were there any consequences OTHER than Mordo.

Comment: Turns out that was a different Mordo, so unrelated to the consequences anyway.